# Convert.ToDateTime() Function returning an Exception Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Recently we are Migrated from `WCF` to `ASP.NET` `WebAPI`

till now it is worked perfectly, but after we migrated to `WCF` we are getting an exception when we converting `string` to `datetime`.

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

Event if the String is Valid DateTime we are getting an error.

Thank You

Comment: Is there any code, what you are trying?

Comment: Yeah @SanjeevS Convert.ToDateTime("08/21/2017 12:04 PM");

Comment: Try using [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or one of its overloads.

Comment: Check culture, may be this format does not match to current culture

Comment: try this one, CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");    
DateTime tempDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2010 12:10:15 PM", culture);

Comment: @Fildor We have tried all the available options, but surprisingly we are getting this errors for some of developers only. for some developer systems it is working fine, but for  some others it is not.

Comment: In that case, I'd support the culture issue. Also, I just reread the docs for Convert. It would not help to switch to DateTime.Parse, anyway (if it is indeed the culture).

Comment: Have you try following globally, yet <system.web>    
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
</system.web>

Comment: @SanjeevS Issue Resolved. Than you....

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `DateTime.TryParse(string inputParam ,Datetime outVariable)` method as it returns boolean value if succeeded and stores the `DateTime` value in out `Datetime` variable.

Please refer to below link for more information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The CultureInfo class holds culture-specific information, such as the associated language, sublanguage, country/region, calendar, and cultural conventions. This class also provides access to culture-specific instances of DateTimeFormatInfo, NumberFormatInfo, CompareInfo, and TextInfo. These objects contain the information required for culture-specific operations, such as casing, formatting dates and numbers, and comparing strings.
The String class indirectly uses this class to obtain information about the default culture. [More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx)

This is due to date format does not match to current culture. You can set default culture information while converting string date format to date time

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); DateTime tempDate = 
Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2010 12:10:15 PM", culture)
```